# Alternative to pg_connect() for PostgreSQL database in PHP running as Apache Module

Tags: php, postgresql, embedded

**This is a peculiar requirement**

I am doing this on a vendor router so I do not have much control over things. I can not load my own PHP or modify php.ini etc.

**Addition:**

Actually PHP is running just as a Apache Module. What options do i have to connect to PostgreSQL database. Though PHP version is PHP Version 5.3.2 - Its is extremely stripped down version of it.

**Requirement:**

There is a PostgreSQL database on this router and I need to access it using the barebones PHP that is available on the router.

Is there a way I can add the PostgreSQL libraries along with my own files and connect to the PostgreSQL database ??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if your PHP has compiled and enabled with this module.
By default is included since PHP 5.1

Comment: I tried this but seems like PostgreSQL PDO driver is also not installed. Getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in

Comment: hmm...I guess you are stuck. No choice, you have to find a way to get postgres module or the Postgres PDO driver loaded into PHP.

Comment: common there has to be some way of doing this :(

Comment: You can however use external postgres client (meaning use bash), but that's again depend on your vendor server. If there is no postgres client, you are stuck again.

Comment: Can you tell me more about this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, if you can get the postgres module (`.so`) for this version of php and if `php.ini` would allow you to do so (not likely) you can dynamically load it.

Comment: No this is not possible. Actually there is no php.ini also on the device. Just a PHP executable.

Comment: Then it most likely doesn't even support dynamic loading. Well, I've never heard of pure-php implementation of postgres protocol.